# Excel Special Characters Legend

Tags: worksheet-function

Would anyone happen to have a list of all formula characters that can be used in a formula?

E.g. "" = Blank/null; * = multiplication; etc.

Comment: `""` does not equal `Blank/Null` it returns a null string which is different. ie. put `=""` in A1 and in A2: `=ISBLANK(A1)` it will return `FALSE`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What special characters can be used in Excel formulas?

> **Equal Sign (=)**
>
> The most commonly used symbol in Excel is the equal (=) sign. Every single formula or function used has to start with equal to let Excel
> know that a formula is being used. If you wish to reference a cell in
> a formula, it has to have an equal sign before the cell address.
> Otherwise, Excel will just enter the cell address as standard text.
>
> **Standard Operators**
>
> The next most common symbols in Excel are the standard operators as used on a calculator: plus (`+`), minus (`–`), multiply (`*`) and divide
> (`/`). Note that the multiplication sign is not the standard
> multiplication sign (`x`) but is depicted by an asterisk (`*`) while the
> division sign is not the standard division sign (`÷`) but is depicted by
> the forward slash (`/`).
>
> **Order of Operations and Adding Parentheses**
>
> The order of operations is always multiplication before addition. However, you can adjust the order of operations by adding parentheses (round brackets) to the formula; any calculations between these parentheses would then be done first before the multiplication.
>
> **Colon (`:`) to Specify a Range of Cells**
>
> In the formula `=SUM(B3:B5)` – the parentheses contain the cell range which the SUM Function needs to add together. This cell range is separated by a colon (`:`) where the first cell reference (B3) is the cell address of the first cell to be included in the range of cells to add together, while the second cell reference (B5) is the cell address of the last cell to be included in the range.
>
> **Dollar Symbol (`$`) in an Absolute Reference**
>
> Used to “fix” a cell address in place in order that a single cell can be used repetitively in multiple formulas by copying formulas between cells.
>
> **Exclamation Point (`!`) to Indicate a Sheet Name**
>
> The exclamation point (!) is critical if you want to create a formula in a sheet and include a reference to a different sheet, eg `=SUM(Sheet1!B2:B4)`
>
> **Square Brackets `[ ]` to Refer to External Workbooks**
>
> The name of the external workbook is enclosed in the square brackets, while the sheet name in that workbook appears after the brackets with an exclamation point at the end.
>
> **Comma (`,`)**
>
> - Refer to Multiple Ranges
> - Separate Arguments in a Function
>
> **Curly Brackets `{ }` in Array Formulas**
>
> An array formula is created by pressing the CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER keys together when entering a formula.
>
> **Other Important Symbols**
>
> ```
> Symbol    Description               Example
> %         Percentage                =B2%
> ^         Exponential operator      =B2^B3
> &         Concatenation             =B2&B3
> >         Greater than              =B2>B3
> <         Less than                 =B2<B3
> >=        Greater than or equal to  =B2>=B3
> <=        Less than or equal to     =B2<=B3
> <>        Not equal to              =B2<>B3
> ```

Source: [What Do the Symbols (&,$,{, etc.) Mean in Formulas? – Excel & Google Sheets - Automate Excel](https://www.automateexcel.com/how-to/signs-symbols-mean-in-formulas/)

See Also:

- [Calculation operators and precedence in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculation-operators-and-precedence-in-excel-48be406d-4975-4d31-b2b8-7af9e0e2878a)
- [Symbols Used in Excel Formula - Excel](https://excelx.com/formula)
- [List of Symbols in Excel Formula (and Their Meanings) - Compute Expert](https://computeexpert.com/english-blog/excel-tips-and-trick/list-of-symbols-in-excel-formula)

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculation-operators-and-precedence-in-excel-48be406d-4975-4d31-b2b8-7af9e0e2878a

Comment: @Hannu Thanks. Added link